# Can I use content-derived deterministic encryption key with hybrid encryption?

Tags: public-key, authenticated-encryption, deterministic-encryption

My use case, making public-key encrypted backups, requires deterministic public-key authenticated encryption. I favour NaCl box, but the way it is generally used is probabilistic and it yields different ciphertext due to the random ephemeral Curve25519 key used in the computation of the shared secret. I am wondering, if it is a bad idea to have deterministic secret key derived from the content.

I have came up with the following scheme for the sender / owner of the data:

1. Given that there is a recipient public key `rpk`.
2. Derive a key for authenticated encryption based on the content.
   $$ keyAE \leftarrow KDF(content) $$
3. Generate random ephemeral Curve25519 key-pair (`sk`, `pk`) and send `pk`.
4. Compute a shared secret `shsk` for the random pair and `rpk` (e.g. X25519).
5. Use `shsk` as one-time pad to conceal `keyAE` and send it.
   $$ sealed\mbox{-}keyAE \leftarrow keyAE \oplus shsk $$
6. Encrypt the content with NaCl secretbox using `keyAE` and send it.

The recipient can then decrypt the `keyAE` using the shared secret and the sealed key and after that decrypt the content.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: And if yes, what's the name of this XOR based key derivation mechanism, because I've thought to use it before as well. I know that there is `CKM_XOR_BASE_AND_DATA` in the PKCS#11 specs (so it is at least not original). Disadvantage of that mechanism is that only one of those is considered a key, which makes the whole operation rather pointless. Maybe it was added to be able to implement HMAC and similar schemes, where you just need the keys to have a large(r) Hamming weight. OTOH, PKCS#11 was not known for their great key management operations, originally (and of course ironically).

Comment: Your scheme could be enhanced by explicitly naming the entities (say A and B). $keyAE \leftarrow KDF(content)$ doesn't make sense, a KDF takes at least two input parameters, a key and data. In your case I think $keyAE \leftarrow H(content)$ would make more sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I believe KDF's input key is irrelevant to how the scheme works. I am using a globally unique context string as suggested in BLAKE3's paper. I am not sure what you mean by naming the entities. I haven't used LaTeX that much, but you can edit the question, if you want to.

Comment: WRT the KDF's input, maybe Blake3 specifies a unique context string, but that's not in the general definition of a KDF, as far as I know. I didn't understand that you just went to the steps for the sender but I think I got it now. I don't think that there is much wrong with your scheme; the shared secret should be fully random and therefore should act like a one-time-pad. I've thought of using XOR too, e.g. when encrypting files with a specific key derived from a password and allowing for password change. You could also wrap the data key with the derived key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for your comments. You are correct about the KDF's function signature. I was thinking more of a function that can derive a key, that can be a hash or HMAC with static key, etc. My idea went though a few iterations in the last few hours and my current concern if it's ok to derive an encryption key from the content itself.

Comment: Are you trying to do [convergent encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_encryption)? What's the rationale? Also, I wouldn't recommend box because I believe it doesn't include the [public keys](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-7) in the key derivation. Furthermore, you may as well use XChaCha20-Poly1305 instead of secretbox, which uses XSalsa20-Poly1305.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 Yes. That's exactly what I am trying to do. I didn't know it was called convergent encryption. It seems I need to read a bit more, thank you!